# Is there any best practice how to detect a first run of the app?

Tags: office-js

Is there an easy and smooth way how to detect if an app is run the first time?
I know, it would be possible to set a cookie and check if it exists but is there another - maybe even better - way?

Comment: is this for the first time ever or for the first time when inserted in the document? (i.e. you can multiple content add-ins on a workbook/presetnation)

Comment: It is for the first time starting an add-in. I know that a user can use a workbook with several content add-ins... but in my case I was rather looking for a best practice when starting an add-in the first time by a user / on a machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I take it that you mean first time on a given computer, as distinct from first time in a given document or first time by a given user. In that case, the cookie, or local storage, is probably your easiest/smoothest strategy. If your add-in is going to have a server-side storage of purchasers/clients/users anyway, then you could also use a flag in that storage. This [SharePoint tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/add-first-run-logic-to-the-provider-hosted-add-in) is an example of a server-side strategy.

Comment: Cool tip with the Sharepoint tutorial, @Rick!
Thanks a bunch!