# Office Add-In with configurable options during installation?

Tags: office-js

Currently I am looking for examples how to write an Office Add-In providing an UI with configurable options for the Add-In alone during installation. And sets them as roaming settings upon once consent is give (submit button).

There is this well-known API for Roaming Settings:
https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/outlook/RoamingSettings.
Plus an API for dialogues, see https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs-pr/blob/master/docs/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins.md.

With these you can show an UI for configuring options. But my missing piece is how to display this during installation?

In other words: how can we ask the user for some parameters before finalising installation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not currently any way to handle the installation event. That's an interesting idea and you should request it at [Office Developer User Voice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/).

In the meantime, consider implementing "first run" logic that prompts the user for her preferences. See this Stack question: [Is there any best practice how to detect a first run of the app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50756976/is-there-any-best-practice-how-to-detect-a-first-run-of-the-app/50766948)

Also, RoamingSettings is available only for Outlook.