# Add Options to Configure Office 365 Add-In During Installation

Tags: office365, powerpoint, office-js, add-in, office-addins

I'm currently writing an updated version of my company's PowerPoint add-in for 365. In previous versions of PowerPoint we've been able to store global settings in configuration files which allow managers to distribute the application across their institutions pre-configured. Because of the way our add-in works, it wouldn't be remotely practical for every end user to have to enter these settings themselves.

I've been scouring the internet for hours for an answer, and the closest I could find was the following SO question from 16 months ago where someone claims that it wasn't possible at the time:

[Office Add-In with configurable options during installation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50808880/office-add-in-with-configurable-options-during-installation)

Does anybody know if this is achievable now? Given that Microsoft have made it so easy to distribute an add-in to everyone in a group, it seems like a massive oversight to not allow any sort of configuration before that happens.

Comment: This an office-js add-in, right? If so, that tag should probably be added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid that this still isn't possible.

Comment: Thanks Rick - thought as much, I couldn't find a single thing about it online. It's a shame but not a game-breaker.